# How to Transfer MySQL Data From Raspberry Pi to my PC

Tags: raspberry-pi, mysql

I've started using Raspberry Pi few days back. I need to transfer a database from my Raspberry Pi to my PC.

I've installed MySQL on the Raspberry Pi and put some data in the database. I've already installed MySQL on my PC. I need to transfer data from the MySQL database on the Raspberry Pi to another MySQL on the PC.

Is this possible through LAN....? 
Or is there another technique to transfer the data from the Raspberry Pi to the PC?

Is there any technique to transfer directly from one MySQL to another MySQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `mysqldump` to output a file containing a bunch of SQL queries that can rebuild your database and then run those queries on your PC database like so:

```bash
pi$ mysqldump -u username -p > mysql.dump

pi$ mysql -u username -p --host=<your pc's ip> < mysql.dump
```

Comment: thanks for ur replay.. so i need to transfer dump file manually to my pc

Comment: is there any direct transfer from mysql to mysql..?

Comment: No, this is the most direct data transfer that I know of. Why?

Comment: then how to transfer my mysql.dump file from raspberry to pc using LAN..?

Comment: There are many ways to transfer a file between computers. If you've got an SSH server on your PC, you can do `scp mysql.dump username@pc:mysql.dump` to transfer over the SSH connection. Personally, I'd just plug a USB drive into the Raspberry Pi and use that to transfer the file

Comment: @siddu Have a look at my answer to see how to simply use mysql to "copy" the dump file.

Comment: You don't have to transfer manually or at all. You can just do `mysqldump -u username -p > mysql.dump` followed by `pi$ mysql --host=[PC-HOST-NAME] -u username -p < mysql.dump`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of copying the file(s), you can pipe the output directly to the remote database.

```
pi_shell> mysqldump -uuser -ppassword --single-transaction database_name | mysql -uuser -ppassword -hremote_mysql_db database_name
```

Comment: I'd say this is the best answer since it actually makes use of the mysql tool's ability to connect to a remote host. Though you may consider putting `-p` instead of `-ppassword` so the password gets prompted instead of typed within the command

Comment: Yes, that's just an example. Even better than having to type in the password every time would be to use [mysql_config_editor](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-config-editor.html)

Comment: -hremote_mysql_db means..? mysql is running in localhost in my pc should i enter like this..  -hlocalhost

Comment: @siddu `-h` is the host parameter. Put the IP adress of your PC there (or the name if you've got a running DNS). I just got used to omit the space between parameter name and value since there's no space allowed the `-p` parameter and the actual password.

Answer (score 0):

Back up the database on the pi,
copy the file on the other computer
then restore it on your computer.

Please see this [site](http://webcheatsheet.com/sql/mysql_backup_restore.php) for reference

Comment: is there any direct transfer from mysql in raspberry pi to mysql in pc...?

Comment: you can write a program to transfer it for you but this is the easiest way that i know